# PyMongo query with multiple statement pointing to the same part of the BSON document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am having problem understanding how to perform queries on nested documents from a web form. Having a set of documents with this structure:

```
{"Colour": "red",
 "feature" :{
    "1" : {"importance" : "high",
            "type": "implementation"},
    "2" : {"importance" : "low",
            "type": "issue"},
 }}
```

My goal is to find the document with some `feature` with multiple specific values. In pymongo I am creating a dictionary that I am populating if the input from the form is not an empty string. Unfortunately, in this way the dictionary may have non-unique keys. Is there a way I can solve this problem?

```
import re
import pymongo

importance_input = "low"
type_input = "issue"
query_A = {"feature" :{"$elemMatch": {"importance":re.compile(importance_input, re.IGNORECASE)}}}
query_B = {"feature" :{"$elemMatch": {"type":re.compile(type_input, re.IGNORECASE)}}}

full_query = {}
if importance_input != "":  
    full_query["feature"] = {"$elemMatch": {"importance":re.compile(importance_input, re.IGNORECASE)}}}

if type_input != "":  
    full_query["feature"] = {"$elemMatch": {"type":re.compile(type_input, re.IGNORECASE)}}}

client.mydb.collection.find(full_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

[$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is the correct operator for imposing multiple conditions on a single array element.

MongoDB has good array query support which will be not usable because your arrays aren't stored as arrays. Perhaps reconsider your schema.